# Mean square displacement for a random walker in a finite system

Tags: stochastic-processes, lattices, random-walks

It is well known that for a simple random walk on a 2D square lattice extending to infinity the mean square displacement of the walk $\langle \mathbf r^2\rangle \propto N \, :(*)$ with $N$ the number of steps taken. There are various ways of showing this, e.g., by writing the end to end vector of the walk as a sum of the displacement vectors taken at each step:
$$
\mathbf R = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \mathbf R_i \tag{1}
$$ 
Squaring it:
$$
R^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N  R_i^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N (\mathbf R_i,\mathbf R_j) \tag{2}
$$ 
with $(\mathbf R_i,\mathbf R_j)$ the dot product between the two vectors, then taking the average of $(2)$ one then arrives at $(*).$

- If we consider the same problem, but for a finite lattice of side $L,$ (in units of the lattice spacing $b$ that we set to $1$ for simplicity), how can we determine the mean square displacement in order to obtain a scaling similar to that in $(*)?$ In other words, is the proportionality in $N$ preserved and how does the finite size of the lattice enter the expression of $\langle \mathbf r^2\rangle?$

Comment: the walker will just cover the square uniformly, with a mean square displacement of $L^2/6$ for large $N$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks a lot for your comment. Can I find a derivation for this somewhere? (Is it commonly known in literature?)

Comment: there is nothing to derive: it is a diffusion process in a finite volume, so the long-time limit of the density will be uniform, and then you just do the integral to find the second moment of the position (this $L^2/6$ is for a walker that starts from the origin).

Comment: here is the integration you requested:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as requested, an explicit calculation: we seek the mean square displacement in the long-time limit for a random walker on an $L\times L$ square; the position of the walker for $N\gg L^2$ is uniformly distributed in that area, hence

$$\langle \delta {r}^2\rangle=\frac{1}{L^2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dy \left[(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\right]=\tfrac{1}{6}L^2+x_0^2+y_0^2,$$

where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the initial position of the walker.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlo. If I may ask: in the above we clearly see that the mean square displacement at long times is dependent on the initial condition $(x_0, y_0),$ so how can it be that we can still say the longtime limit of the density (for the position of the walker) will be uniform regardless of the initial condition?

Comment: the second moment $\langle\delta x^2\rangle=L^2/12+x_0^2$ depends on the initial position, but the variance $\langle\delta x^2\rangle-\langle \delta x\rangle^2=L^2/12$ is independent of the initial position, so there is no contradiction with the uniform distribution.

Comment: Ahh that's neat, sorry for not noticing that on my own and instead asking it rather naively. When people do similar mean square displacement calculations for systems with more than one particle, does one just add the corresponding $\langle \delta r^2\rangle$'s to get the total displacement? Say for two particles for example.